# Google Analytics wrong data display when filtered by amount of days

Tags: google-analytics

In google analytics, when i view data for last 1 month and rollover on 30th sep it shows 378 sessions as shown below:

[image]

If i just change the dates to the same day that is 30th sep, i get 2,666 sessions as shown below:

[image]

I changed the precision level too, but still it doesn't work. I like to see the same numbers in 1 month data as seen in single day data. What should i do?

Comment: Have you looked at the "Hourly" report to see a breakdown within that day?

Comment: Yes Stephen, it shows total 2,666.

Comment: Are there hours that are out of whack?